# Ksh script: How to remain in ssh and continue the script

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

So for my script I want to ssh into a remote host and remain in the remote host after the script ends and also have the directory changed to match the remote host when the script ends.

```
#!/bin/ksh

ssh -t -X mylogin@myremotemachine 'cd $HOME/bin/folder1; echo $PWD; ssh -q -X ssh mylogin@myremotemachine; cd $HOME/bin/folder2; echo $PWD'
```

The PWD gets changed correctly before the second ssh. The reason for the second ssh is because it ends the script in the correct remote host but it will not retain the directory change which I attempted by putting commands after it but they won't execute.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What particular task do you want to solve ? It looks like that you need `screen` utility

Comment: My script sshs snd executed data analysis and outputs it into a folder on the remote host. When the script is over, the user is booted out of the remote host.

I want the user to remain in the remote host and be in the directory that the data analysis was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just launch a shell at the end of the command list:

```
ssh -t -X mylogin@myremotemachine 'cd $HOME/bin/folder1; echo $PWD; ssh -q -X ssh mylogin@myremotemachine; cd $HOME/bin/folder2; echo $PWD; ksh'
```

If you want the shell to be a login one (i.e. one that reads `.profile`), use `exec -l`:

```
ssh -t -X mylogin@myremotemachine 'cd $HOME/bin/folder1; exec -l ksh'
```

If the remote server uses an old `ksh` release that doesn't support the `exec -l` builtin and if `bash` or `ksh93` is available, here is a workaround:

```
ssh -t -X mylogin@myremotemachine 'cd $HOME/bin/folder1; exec bash -c "exec -l ksh"'
```

Comment: This does work:

ssh -t -X mylogin@myremotemachine 'cd $HOME/bin/folder1; ksh'

but how do I make it look like the original shell instead of the basic one? I think I need to execute the .profile now how do I add that onto that command without having the user to type it in all the time?

Comment: I get a ksh: -l: not found message.

Comment: What OS is running the remote host and what version of `ksh`?

Comment: AIX drop1 3 5 000970